# External Javascript load but not working

Tags: javascript, loading, external

I have a script that when is placed in the footer.php works OK but if I place it in a external .js file is not working. Load OK but not works.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(function() { 
    !function(t){"use strict";function e(t,e,n,o,r){var i=Array.prototype.forEach,f=t instanceof Node?t:document.querySelector(t);if(!f)return!1;var s=f.querySelectorAll(e);if(0===s.length)return!1;n="number"==typeof n&&isFinite(n)&&Math.floor(n)===n?n:6,f.style.width="";var u=f.getBoundingClientRect().width,l=s[0].getBoundingClientRect().width+n,a=Math.max(Math.floor((u-n)/l),1),c=0;u=l*a+n+"px",f.style.width=u,f.style.position="relative";for(var d=[],p=[],h=0;a>h;h++)p.push(h*l+n),d.push(n);i.call(s,function(t){var e=d.slice(0).sort(function(t,e){return t-e}).shift();e=d.indexOf(e);var r=p[e],f=d[e],s=["webkitTransform","MozTransform","msTransform","OTransform","transform"];return t.style.position="absolute",o||i.call(s,function(e){t.style[e]="translate("+r+"px,"+f+"px)"}),d[e]+=t.getBoundingClientRect().height+n,c+=1,o?o(t,r,f,c):void 0});var m=d.slice(0).sort(function(t,e){return t-e}).pop();f.style.height=m+"px","function"==typeof r&&r(s)}"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return e}):"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=e:t.minigrid=e}(this);
    (function(){
        minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
            minigrid('.grid', '.grid-item');
        });
    })();
    });                                                                     
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `not working`? Is there an error? How's your external js file loaded?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {` and `$(function() { ` is redundant. `window.addEventListener('resize', function() {` can be simplified to `$(window).resize(function() {`

Comment: Mladen Ilic, with not working I mean that the script does nothing. I can not see any error in the web inspector. I load the .js file from the header.pho with the next calling: <script src="http://www.labonitaink.com/wp-content/themes/Aurum%20Theme/js/soto.js"></script>

Comment: Roland Starke, thank you very much for your corrections.